# Scrolling gets cut off on 3.5 inch iOS devices

Tags: ios, user-interface

The application is using storyboard and I am noticing that for 3.5 inch devices, the scrolling gets cut off (specifically for tableView). The tableView is inside a nav controller which is inside a tab bar controller. When I un-check "Use Auto-Layout", I no longer encounter the bug. What does this mean and how can I fix it to work with auto-layout?

Comment: It means your constraints are probably set incorrectly.  Try removing your height constraint, and replace it with a constraint from the bottom of the table view to the bottom of its superview.

Comment: It will be easier for you if you go through a tutorial and learn about auto-layout http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2

Comment: Thanks, setting constraints helped!

Comment: How can this be done programmatically?